# No agrupar (GROUP BY) los campos nulos o vacíos en una consulta MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con datos generales de asistentes de limpieza con un código de privilegio de entrada, y necesito elaborar una consulta la cual agrupe por tipo  de privilegio, pero los que no tienen ningún tipo de privilegio no los agrupe y coloque en una fila más en el resultado de esa consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la consulta de donde agrupo por privilegio, agrupa todo, inclusive los campos que son vacíos o nulos.

Debería de agrupar los datos que no son nulos y que coinciden y los que son nulos o vacíos no agruparlos sino mostrarlos en una fila uno por uno.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`id_asistente`) AS Cantidad_Privilegiados 
FROM `asistentes_limpieza` 
GROUP BY Privilegio;
```

Lo cual muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La agrupación debe ser solo por tipo de privilegio.

Lo intente con un `IS NOT NULL` pero el resultado es el mismo y debería de mostrarlos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: NO GRITES, POR FAVOR

Comment: Wagner, evita el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas en tus publicaciones, en internet se entiende como si estuvieses gritando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puedes valer del operador `UNION` para hacer dos consultas.

- En la primera usas `WHERE` para indicarle que solo agrupe las que no son vacías
- En la segunda usas `WHERE` para indicar que liste las vacías o las nulas y que no use agrupamiento

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`id_asistente`) AS Cantidad_Privilegiados
FROM asistentes_limpieza
WHERE Privilegio <> ''
GROUP BY Privilegio

UNION

SELECT *, 0 AS Cantidad_Privilegiados
FROM asistentes_limpieza
WHERE Privilegio = '' OR Privilegio IS NULL
;
```

**Probado en `sqliddle` con el siguiente esquema:**

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE asistentes_limpieza (
    id_asistente INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Area VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Actividad INT NOT NULL,
    Privilegio VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_asistente)
);

-- data
INSERT INTO asistentes_limpieza
    (id_asistente, Area, Actividad, Privilegio)
VALUES
    (1, 'PATIO DE SERVICIO', 1, 'DISCAPACIDAD'),
    (2, 'PATIO DE SERVICIO', 1, ''),
    (3, 'SALA 1', 3, 'PROBLEMATICO'),
    (4, 'SALA 1', 3, 'PROBLEMATICO'),
    (5, 'SALA 16', 3, 'PROBLEMATICO'),
    (6, 'FACHADA', 10, 'DISCAPACIDAD'),
    (7, 'FACHADA', 10, ''),
    (8, 'FACHADA', 10, NULL)
;
```

La salida queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fijate que si el privilegio es null la primera parte del union te los cuenta y en la segunda no te los lista.

Comment: @GavilanPatagonico Gracias por la observación. Acabo de correr una prueba agregando un valor null y obtuve el resultado que muestro en la edición de la respuesta.